# Google Maps Geolocation API over http

Tags: delphi, geolocation, google-api

I'm implementing the Google Maps Geolocation API as explained here. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/

The problem is my server is implemented in delphi and using https is quite complex,

**is there a way to use this API in plain http?**

I know there are some security issues, but this feature in particular will only exists in a cache subsystem where no sensitive data is ever send or stored.

Comment: I'm not shure, may be you'll find something here: http://www.delphipraxis.net/157004-google-maps-ueber-com-component-object-model.html

Comment: https using Indy or other available libraries is indeed very easy. What do you find complex?

Comment: I just downloaded the dll's but i cant find how to use them inside or load them in my project.